# Different behavior between iOS 4.3 and 5.0 with UIDatePicker code execution

Tags: iphone, ios4, datepicker, ios5, uidatepicker

I have a perplexing problem in trying to sort out different behavior of the same code on an iPhone 4S running iOS 5.0 and an iPad running iOS 4.3.

The view controller code is associated with a view with a date picker to enter a date of birth. Via Interface Builder the date picker is associated with the received action "Value Changed" directed toward the view controller method -(IBAction)birthDate: (id)sender:

```
-(IBAction)birthDate: (id)sender {

//Code here executed when date of birth entered. Should not be executed when view loads.


}
```

It is very important in the app that this code NOT be executed when the view loads. I have demonstrated with a breakpoint insertion that this code does not execute when the view loads with iOS 5.0, but does execute when the view loads with iOS 4.3, causing a real problem with the program (the default birthdate becomes interpreted as an entered birthdate). I very much would appreciate advice on how to prevent the IBAction code from executing in iOS 4.3 unless the user changes the default date of birth. I also am very curious as to why this difference in behavior should exist. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a documented change to UIPickerView's behaviour in iOS 5.0 ([Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_0/_index.html))
One way to get around it on iOS 4.3 would be to have a BOOL that is set to YES at the beginning of `loadView` and NO at the end.

Your value changed method `birthDate:` could then check that this BOOL value is NO before handling the change.

```
-(void)loadView
{
    isViewLoading = YES; // isViewLoading is a BOOL ivar
    // load view
}
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    // what ever else
    isViewLoading = NO;
}
-(IBAction)birthDate:(id)sender
{
    if (isViewLoading) return;
    // handle change
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Unfortunately, same problem still occurs with iOS 4.3. With this code and sequential breakpoints placed, the sequence of execution when the view loads is loadView, then viewDidLoad, then the method birthDate (with the boolean NO at that point). Any additional suggestions I could try?

Comment: try -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { [super viewDidAppear:animated]; }

Comment: Excellent! The execution sequence of viewDidLoad, then birthDate, then viewDidAppear works perfectly now with the boolean scheme you suggested, running iOS 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, and 5.0. Thanks for the great help.